# Permutation problem about ordering objects in a line (translation issue)

Tags: probability, permutations

I was solving problems with permutations and combinations when I found the following:
"Eight children of different ages stand in a random order in a line. Find the number of different ways this can be done if none of the three youngest children stand next to each other."
My problem here is that when I read the text (not a native English speaker) I understand that I can't place 2 children next to each other and that I also cannot place 3 children next to each other. But when I checked the answer someone else gave they considered that putting 2 of the youngest children next to each other was acceptable (just not the 3 youngest children each next to the other).
Is my interpretation wrong? If so, how would you rewrite the problem for my interpretation to be valid?
Thank you!

Comment: The way it reads, I would interpret the same way as you did.

Comment: But I can see how translating that into another language might not come out as intended.